# How to connect Command with adapter pattern

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, command, adapter

I have a software module built using **command pattern.**(sometimes called command processor)

The **commands** in this processor are executed by calling **external executables**, tools, services, etc., for which I am using **adapters** for each type of tools or services being invoked.

The problem is, that a single type of command(with different contents) **can execute different types of externel executables** depending upon the content of command object, which will **require different adapters**

i.e., the **Receiver/supplier**(implementation of command's execution) of the command can **choose different types of adapters** depending upon the context.

Question is,

**a)**  Am I required to split a single generic command object into multiple command objects so that their mapping with the adapters become one-to-one.

Or am I required to place a facade in the form of Receiver/supplier of the command object, so that the function of choosing appropriate adapter is delegated to this facade(which is command's Receiver).

**b)** Is the use of the term "adapter pattern" correct when I say that i am mapping command object parameters to the interfaces of external executables at the supplier level?

Answer (score 1):

a. I would say 'No' to creating multiple `Command` classes. You will be mixing the two abstractions, and possibly have to write too many `Command` classes.

b. I would probably use `Strategy` rather than `Adapater` pattern for this part. I would create a new interface `ExecutionStrategy`. Command object can choose an `ExecutionStrategy`. The `ExecutionStrategy` can be created (or supplied from a pool of already created objects) by a `Factory`. The `Factory` can be a part of the abstract Command class or be a separate 
`ExecutionStrategyFactory` class.